# Webex Macro Editor have \ in front of ' by javascript

Tags: javascript, editor, special-characters, webex

I want to send an request with an URL with '. And it always had \ in front of the '. Thus, the format will be wrong. Does anyone know how to fix it?

For example,

```
console.log("'")
```

It will show on the terminal

```
\'
```

But I only want

```
'
```

I have use replace funciton. It still can't work. I think the editor is the reason!